Inline кнопки в ТГ боте на telebot
Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы после нажатия на одну Inline кнопку вызывался следующий блок кнопок.
Проблема: следующий блок кнопок не работает.
Вот код:
import telebot

from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('Token')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    itmbtn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Connect a new channel', callback_data='1')
    itmbtn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Subscribtion', callback_data='2')
    itmbtn3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Button 3', callback_data='3')
    itmbtn4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Button 4', callback_data='4')

    markup.add (itmbtn1, itmbtn2, itmbtn3, itmbtn4)
    bot.send_photo (message.chat.id, photo=open('Path', 'rb'), caption="Good to see you! It's ChanellManagerBot!", reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def answer(call): 
    global KeyboardData
    if call.data == '1':
        KeyboardData = 1
    elif call.data == '2':
        KeyboardData = 2
    elif call.data == '3':
        KeyboardData = 3
    elif call.data == '4':
        KeyboardData = 4

    if call.data == '1':
        bot.send_message (call.message.chat.id, "Assigning bot as a channel administrator: \n1) Open chanell settings \n2) Open 'Administrators' tab \n3) Click 'Add administrator' and paste 'Bot_Name' \nBot connected!")

    elif call.data == '2':
        NumPerWeek = 0
        markup2 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        itmbtn5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='3', callback_data='5', KeyboardData = 5)
        itmbtn6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='5', callback_data='6', KeyboardData = 6)
        itmbtn7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='7', callback_data='7', KeyboardData = 7)
        itmbtn8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='14', callback_data='8', KeyboardData = 8)
        itmbtn9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Custom', callback_data='9', KeyboardData = 9)
        
        markup2.add (itmbtn5, itmbtn6, itmbtn7, itmbtn8, itmbtn9)
        bot.send_message (call.message.chat.id, 'Select number of posts per week:', reply_markup=markup2)

        while NumPerWeek == 0:
            if KeyboardData == 5:
                NumPerWeek = 3
            elif KeyboardData == 6:
                NumPerWeek = 5
            elif KeyboardData == 7:
                NumPerWeek = 7
            elif KeyboardData == 8:
                NumPerWeek = 14
            else:
                pass

        if NumPerWeek != 0:    
            bot.send_message (call.message.chat.id, f"Selected - {NumPerWeek}")


bot.infinity_polling()


Вы блокируете поток своим циклом, он вам тут не нужен.
